# Angular + requirejs - the controller cannot pick up ajax return data from the factory?

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, angularjs, requirejs

My controller cannot pick up the data that processed from `$http.get()` in requirejs environment. Any idea how can I fix it?

### UserFactory.js

```
define(['app'], function (app) {

  app.module1.factory('UserFactory', ['$http', function($http) { 
    //your minsafe controller 
    var factory = {};

    factory.getUsers = function(){
      $http.get('api.php').success(function(data) {
          // here the data from the api is assigned to a variable named users
          return data; // [{"id":"1","name":"Big Kev","email":"bigkev@example.com"},{"id":"2","name":"Judy","email":"punk@example.net"},{"id":"3","name":"Suzy","email":"suzy@example.com"},{"id":"4","name":"Joey","email":"sheena@example.org"},{"id":"5","name":"DeeD","email":"deedee@example.net"}]
      }); 
    }; 

    return factory;
  }]);

});
```

### view.js,

```
define(['app'], function (app) {

  app.module1.controller('View1Ctrl', ['$scope','UserFactory', function($scope,userFactory) { 
    //your minsafe controller 
    $scope.message = "Message from View1Ctrl"; 
    $scope.users = userFactory.getUsers();
    console.log($scope.users); // undefined
  }]);
});
```

as you can see, I get `undefined` for `$scope.users`. It seems that `console.log($scope.users);` is executed before `$http.get('api.php')` in the factory. How can I fix this then?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This has nothing to do with Require; it is a very common misconception about how asynchronous code runs (especially promises).

You see `factory.getUsers()` makes an asynchronous call. The response will be available at a later time and `success` will be called with the response data at that later time. On the other hand, `$scope.users = userFactory.getUsers()` is synchronous. It is almost guaranteed that the async call wll *NOT* have returned by the time the next statement runs. And even if it *has* returned, the callback will *NOT* have run because Javascript is single threaded in the browser.

Moreover you have another serious fault: the `success` callback is "procedural" in the sense that it receives the response and has to do something with it. *Its return value is disregarded!*

To use promises (or at least `$http`) correctly in this case, change `factory.getUsers` to return the `$http` promise:

```
factory.getUsers = function(){
    return $http.get('api.php');
};
```

And change the controller to use the promise or the `success`/`error` callbacks:

```
// option (1) with promise
userFactory.getUsers().then(function(response) {
    $scope.users = response.data;
});

// option (2) callback
userFactory.getUsers().success(function(data) {
    $scope.users = data;
});
```